# Getting the leaf from a path string in Windows Command Prompt/batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a variable that stores a path, say "C:\temp\foo\blabla\foobar" I need to get the leaf value, i.e. "foobar".
In PoweShell this would be really easy, but I need to do this in a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 1):

from command prompt:

```
for %a in ("C:\temp\foo\blabla\foobar") do echo %~nxa
```

from batch file:

```
for %%a in ("C:\temp\foo\blabla\foobar") do echo %%~nxa
```

to replace the value:

```
@echo off
set new_value=new
set "path=C:\temp\foo\blabla\foobar"
for %%a in ("%path%") do set new_path=%%~dpa%new_value%
echo %new_path%
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I replace the literal string with a variable? And how do I store the result in another variable? (in a  batch file) This thing is so confusing...

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to do this:

robocopy %2 \\mycomputer\deploy\%x /E 
where %x is the leaf of path stored in %a

Comment: I tried that, it completely screwed the pooch. I wrote this:
@ECHO OFF
set new_value=new
for %%a in ("%2") do set new_path=%%~dpa%new_value%

robocopy %2 \\mycomputer\deploy\%new_path% /E

my build process now goes through 30-second loops of waiting and retrying. Funny thing is it's trying to access a path that consists of \\mycomputer\[path stored in parameter %1]\new
Any idea where I could have made a mistake? The value from %1 appearing is the most surprising to me, I'm not using that variable anywhere in the command sequence.